# iOS: Objective How To Get One Image At A Time To Glow, As Finger Is Dragged Over Each Of A Series Of Images

Tags: ios, uiview, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

Objective: To get one image at a time to glow, as finger is dragged over each of a series of images.

In an attempt to figure this out on my own, I tried to update the Alpha of the touched image to 1.00 while setting all others in the series of images to alpha 0.25 as finger drags over each individual image via touchesMoved?  However my methods below did not produce the desired result.

Artwork for Glow overlay for each of the eight images is created in viewDidLoad using this pattern:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    Glow *imageOne  = [[Glow alloc] 
                          initWithNibName:@"ImageOne" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.glowOneView = imageOne;
    [imageOne release];

    [self.glowOneView setTag:101];
    [self.glowOneView setAlpha:0.25];
    [self.glowOneView setCenter:CGPointMake(160,135)];

    [self.view insertSubview:self.glowOneView atIndex:11];
}
```

(repeating the above pattern to uniquely create each of the remaining eight images).

touchesMoved pattern looks like this:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{    
    NSLog(@"Touches Began");
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch view] == glowOneView) {


        [glowOneView   setAlpha:1.00];
        [glowTwoView   setAlpha:0.25];
        [glowThreeView setAlpha:0.25];
        [glowFourView  setAlpha:0.25];
        [glowFiveView  setAlpha:0.25];
        [glowSixView   setAlpha:0.25];
        [glowSevenView setAlpha:0.25];
        [glowEightView setAlpha:0.25];

        NSLog(@"Began Button One");
    }

    else if ([touch view] == glowTwoView) {

        [glowOneView   setAlpha:0.25];
        [glowTwoView   setAlpha:1.00];
        [glowThreeView setAlpha:0.25];
        [glowFourView  setAlpha:0.25];
        [glowFiveView  setAlpha:0.25];
        [glowSixView   setAlpha:0.25];
        [glowSevenView setAlpha:0.25];
        [glowEightView setAlpha:0.25];

        NSLog(@"Began Button Two");
    }
...
```

(repeating the above pattern to uniquely handle each of the remaining eight images).

The code snippets above will glow the first image touched, but as you drag around the view touchesMoved won't update the alpha for any subsequent image the finger is dragged over, until the touch is released and a new touch is initiated.

The Console shows the touchesMoved NSLog from the first image touched only, and continually repeats the NSLog for that first image touched for as long as the finger is dragged, no matter which image is subsequently under the dragging finger.

I would really appreciate your advice and any example that replaces or updates the above methods to produce the desired result of getting one image at a time to glow, as a finger is dragged over each of a series of images.

Thank you,

Comment: Off topic, you should consider putting your views in an array and iterating / setting property values at indexes. It'll make accessing them easier.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented something similar to what you describe. Assuming this code is in the view that contains your Glow views, you need to do a couple of things: 1) have your container view intercept touch events by returning itself from `hitTest:withEvent:`, and 2) in `touchesMoved:withEvent:`, call UIView's implementation of `hitTest:withEvent:` to figure out which view the touch is in.

```
-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // intercept all touches inside container
    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
        return self;        
    }
    return nil;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // figure out which view the touch is in
    UIView *view = [super hitTest:[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self] withEvent:nil];

    // highlight Glow subview under touch
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[Glow class]]) {
        [view setAlpha:1.0];
    }

    // un-highlight all other Glow subviews
    for (UIView *subview in [self subviews]) {
        if (subview != view && [subview isKindOfClass:[Glow class]]) {
            [subview setAlpha:0.25];
        }
    }    
}
```

You'll probably want to also implement `touchesBegan:withEvent:` to highlight the view before the touch starts moving and `touchesCancelled:withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent:` to un-highlight all.